# How to deploy an Angular + Springboot projects to heroku

Tags: maven, spring-boot, heroku, web-deployment

I'm new to web development and I have scanned most questions about this, but my condition is different.
[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SAuT.png)

I put the front-end folder in the project root folder, so when I build the Spring project, I use maven to build the Angular project and move it to the `target/classes/static`

Here is my maven plugins

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v9.5.0</nodeVersion>

                            <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run-script build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>${basedir}/angular-client</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/angular-client/dist</directory >
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and this worked on my local laptop.

```
    [

INFO] Scanning for projects...
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Building spring-angular4 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ spring-angular4 >>>
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ spring-angular4 ---
        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
        [INFO] Copying 7 resources
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ spring-angular4 ---
        [INFO] Node v9.5.0 is already installed.
        [INFO] NPM 5.6.0 is already installed.
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ spring-angular4 ---
        [INFO] Running 'npm install' in /Users/tingyugu/Desktop/test/spring-angular4/angular-client
        [INFO] up to date in 10.183s
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm run-script build) @ spring-angular4 ---
        [INFO] Running 'npm run build' in /Users/tingyugu/Desktop/test/spring-angular4/angular-client
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] > angular-client@0.0.0 build /Users/tingyugu/Desktop/test/spring-angular4/angular-client
        [INFO] > ng build --prod
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] Date: 2018-02-09T17:42:29.707Z
        [INFO] Hash: e3ae517dae714ceb6276
        [INFO] Time: 21657ms
        [INFO] chunk {0} polyfills.f20484b2fa4642e0dca8.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
        [INFO] chunk {1} main.83dbbe868aaf28369eae.bundle.js (main) 152 kB [initial] [rendered]
        [INFO] chunk {2} styles.9c0ad738f18adc3d19ed.bundle.css (styles) 79 bytes [initial] [rendered]
        [INFO] chunk {3} inline.73203cbab5522a17c017.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ spring-angular4 ---
        [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
        [INFO] Copying 1 resource
        [INFO] Copying 0 resource
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ spring-angular4 ---
        [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

Now I want to deploy the project to the heroku, and it give me the errors

```
remote:        [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ spring-angular4 ---
remote:        [INFO] Running 'npm install' in /tmp/build_9d47c61eca7fea7b7c973f2a0ae33b98/angular-client
remote:        [WARNING] npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_9d47c61eca7fea7b7c973f2a0ae33b98/angular-client/package.json'
remote:        [ERROR] npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
remote:        [WARNING] npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_9d47c61eca7fea7b7c973f2a0ae33b98/angular-client/package.json'
remote:        [INFO] up to date in 0.069s
remote:        [WARNING] npm WARN angular-client No description
remote:        [WARNING] npm WARN angular-client No repository field.
remote:        [WARNING] npm WARN angular-client No README data
remote:        [WARNING] npm WARN angular-client No license field.
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [INFO] 
remote:        [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm run-script build) @ spring-angular4 ---
remote:        [INFO] Running 'npm run build' in /tmp/build_9d47c61eca7fea7b7c973f2a0ae33b98/angular-client
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! path /tmp/build_9d47c61eca7fea7b7c973f2a0ae33b98/angular-client/package.json
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! errno -2
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! syscall open
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_9d47c61eca7fea7b7c973f2a0ae33b98/angular-client/package.json'
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! enoent 
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        [ERROR] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-09T17_37_34_200Z-debug.log
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time: 7.063 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-09T17:37:34Z
remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 26M/372M
```

I know the reason is that when heroku build the project the path will change, but how to resolve this issue, and would some tell me something about what will happen when heroku build the project?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the reason is that, angular-client is a submodule of the project, I remove the submodule config from .git and git push project again, it works.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error, Can you please explain what you mean by remove the submodule config from .git?